# What's the difference between kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar and kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8PlanarFullRange?

Tags: ios, yuv, core-video

According the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1563591-pixel_format_identifiers?language=objc), it seems `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` to `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange` is what `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar` to `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8PlanarFullRange`.

But the documentation do not specified the range of later i420 pixel formats. What's the difference?

Comment: There exists two sets of 8-bit "ranges" in video: "full/pc/jpeg" range is coded using 0-255, and "limited/tv/mpeg" range is from 16-235. The limited range is from the days when a ~10% headroom/footroom was left to allow for analog filtering without clipping. Video coded with "limited" range assumes values with luma<=16 are black; If you decode these values assuming they're "full" range, this will show up as a dark grey.